# Comparing Two Excel Files using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I want to compare 2 excel files using Power Automate which are stored in SharePoint Documents , and if any of the column rows contains another values , a mail should be forwarded saying the values are not matching.
So for this i want to create Power Automate Flow

Answer (score 1):

This shall be challening with Power-automate. I personally would go with some code. I believe you have already googled for the same issue.

But I could see below 2 Post which can be of your help.

1. [List item](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Comparing-Excel-Files/td-p/119721)
2. [List item](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Compare-2-Excel-Spreadsheets/td-p/487909)